# Avoiding repetitive "content_for" in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actioncontroller

I have a submenu placed in my layout wich differs from controller to controller, but not between each controllers method views. What I am currently doing is the following:

```
<% content_for( :submenu ) do %>
    <%= render :partial => 'submenus/correct_submenu' %>
<% end %>
```

In every view for a method

My applications layout then has this in it

```
<%= yield :submenu %>
```

However, this feels kind of repetitive, doing it for each view. Is there some way to do this per controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My suggest is to have a convention for this, so if you have a `ProductsController` then the submenu would be `submenus/products_menu`.  This way you can write a helper that looks like:

```
def render_submenu
  content_for(:submenu) { render :partial => "submenus/#{controller.controller_name}_menu" }
end
```

You can then call this by doing:

```
<%= render_submenu %>
```

You could then make this the default content_for the submenus and only specify the content if it needs to be different.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use [nested layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) to nest a specific controller's layout under the application layout, by creating a file like so:

```
# app/view/layouts/<controller_name>.html.erb
<% content_for( :submenu ) do %>
  <%= render :partial => 'submenus/correct_submenu' %>
<% end %>
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

With this method, you don't have to modify a bunch of view files.